# HTTP client request Authorization: Negotiate option

Tags: http, kerberos

I would like to access HDFS files using webhdfs. Curl gives me an option of using --negotiate -u: user option to use existing kerberos token. How do we pass the negotiate option using HTTP request headers. I know that we can use "Authorization: Negotiate" option. However, I get the following error.

```
GSSException: Defective token detected
```

Comment: The WebHDFS tutorial is quite clear: you don't have to tweak the headers. The HTTP client library will manage the "negotiation" automatically *(1st contact, then 401 response, then 2nd contact with a hash of the Kerberos token in the headers)*

Comment: Search StackOverflow about `SPNego`

Comment: It happens with curl when you include --negotiate option. But it returns authentication required when you use a java HttpClient library.

Comment: Linux or Windows? Kerberos back-end is Microsoft AD or MIT Kerberos? >> on Windows, all browsers (and curl) use Microsoft SSPI libraries to access the Windows credentials cache; while on Linux they use regular GSSAPI and the regular cache. Java always uses GSSAPI; on Windows it may failover to the Microsoft cache, unless it's locked. Etc etc etc.

Comment: `java.net.HttpURLConnection` plus a custom JAAS conf (passed via prop `java.security.auth.login.config`) works for me. Note that in GitBook _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the madness beyond the gate"_ it is explicitly stated that Apache HTTP libs **sometimes** work with SPNego. If the core Hadoop contributors can't make it work consistently, better avoid it...

Comment: I used the following piece of code to get an inputStream of the file using the webhdfs. The AuthenticatedURL is provided by the hadoop-auth library.
    val token: AuthenticatedURL.Token = new AuthenticatedURL.Token()
    val conn: HttpURLConnection = new AuthenticatedURL().openConnection(url, token)
    val source = StreamConverters.fromInputStream(conn.getInputStream)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:
kinit -kt ${your_keytab_file_full_path} ${your_principal}
curl --negotiate -u : -o ${your_keytab_file_full_path} ${URL}